# ASP.NET required validator change from client side

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, validation

I wonder whether it is possible to change error message of required validator from the client side. I do not want to create another custom validator.

I already have validators required and range both checking one textbox. When a user types the number of certain lengths I make an AJAX call to check if this number is already in the database. In case it is I would like to "fire" one of those validators with a custom message and set IsValid property to false.

I have tried

```
$("#<%=vldReqID.ClientID%>").attr('errormessage', 'User already exists');
```

which I have find on the internet but it does not work for me.

Is there a way how to "inject" ASP.NET validator or I have to add my custom validator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTML, a Validator error message is nothing more that a `span` element with `display:none` as style. So you can just change the contents of that span element.

```
document.getElementById("<%= RequiredFieldValidator1.ClientID %>").innerHTML = "Error message changed!";
```

Comment: Is there also a way to how to mark it as invalid in order not to allow page postback?

Comment: Then it would be easier to create a custom validator that can validate multiple situations.